# How to call watch listener in another controller for scope property of parent scope when that scope property is changed by other child controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I'm a new for AngularJS

I have a question about $scope.$watch method.

I have three controller.
One is named "ParentCtrl"and the others are "FirstChildCtrl" and "SecondChildCtrl".
ParentCtrl's scope has a property named "parentVal" which has watcher by FirstChildCtrl's scope.

When I changed "parentVal" in ParentCtrl's scope, watch listener in FirstChildCtrl's scope has been called.
But When "parentVal" is changed by SecondChildCtrl's scope, that listener couldn't be called.

What is the difference between them,
and How to call watch listener in FirstChildCtrl's scope by SecondChildCtrl's scope.

the code I tried is in Plunker
Pluker's link is below 
https://plnkr.co/nTxxlUEniUWKgO5IKVAo?p=info

HTML

```
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angularScript.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="parentCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="firstChildCtrl"></div>
  <div ng-controller="secondChildCtrl"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('WatchTest', []);
app.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', 
  function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.parentVal = 0;

    $scope.$watch('parentVal', function() {
      console.log('parentVal has changed!!!, A message from parentCtrl');
    });
  }
]);

app.controller('firstChildCtrl', [ '$scope', '$interval',
  function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.$watch('parentVal', function() {
      console.log('parentVal has changed!!!, A message from firstChildCtrl');
    });
  }
]);

app.controller('secondChildCtrl', [ '$scope', '$interval',
  function($scope, $interval) {
    $interval(
      function() {
        $scope.parentVal++;
      }, 1000
    );
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Nesting controllers using ng-controller results in normal prototypal
>   inheritance.

This means `firstChildCtrl`, `secondChildCtrl` has access to `parentVal` via the `prototypal` inheritance. The moment you increment/change `parentVal` in `secondChildCtrl`, it will create its own `parentVal` property and assign the new value to that and for any future reference to `parentVal` it will refer its own property rather than going up the prototype chain.

If you use an object in your parent controller and update its properties the result would be what you expect.

e.g. let's say the object is data. Then the code would look like this

```
app.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', 
  function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.parentVal = 0;

    $scope.$watch('data.parentVal', function() {
      console.log('parentVal has changed!!!, A message from parentCtrl');
    });
  }
]);

app.controller('firstChildCtrl', [ '$scope', '$interval',
  function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.$watch('data.parentVal', function() {
      console.log('parentVal has changed!!!, A message from firstChildCtrl');
    });
  }
]);

app.controller('secondChildCtrl', [ '$scope', '$interval',
  function($scope, $interval) {
    $interval(
      function() {
        $scope.data.parentVal++;
      }, 1000
    );
  }
])
```

With this code you would see the watchers firing, when the value is updated in the `secondChildCtrl`

Refer [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ng-controller) for more information.